# Java calendar engine

Tags: java, calendar

Does anybody know any engines for calendar implementation?

For example, which accepts event definition object (it can be iCalendar-style) and current date as input and outputs whether this date matches event definition?

Answer (score 4):

Hmm. Calendaring is hard.

I've had *very* mixed experiences with [iCal4j](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Main_Page) - it's not too smart about time zones in some places, but after a bit of work it can be just about okay. That will allow you to parse iCal entries.

Beyond that, I'd based everything you possibly can on [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). Definitely avoid the built-in `java.util.Date`/`Calendar` classes as far as possible.

Comment: +1 for avoiding java.util.Calendar. It is a total piece of crap.

Comment: Thank you, this is useful, but nevertheless, the main point is about figuring out which events are scheduled for particular date (like MS outlook calendar). And I couldn't find any libraries for that, though I doubting that no one has ever solved that problem

Comment: @glaz666: iCal4j and a bit of effort should be able to tell you that.